# How to allow a specific property to be book for 2 weeks instead of 1

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, plugins

My website imports rental data from a JSON API into a custom post type in WordPress.
Currently, all properties can only be booked for 1 week, but there is a request to allow a specific
property to be booked for 2 weeks instead of 1.
Also, we need to be sure we are not showing this specific property in the results if the two weeks
following the selected week are not available. For instance, if it gets booked out two weeks, then
another two weeks with a single-week gap between those reservations, it can't show on the site
if someone searches for that middle week.

Updates to JSON request for weekly pricing. And there is the file root /wp-content/plugins/home-away-sync/avail-weekly.php

avail.weekly.php file

```
$isDebug = false;
$wp_start = microtime(true);

define('SHORTINIT', true); 

require_once '../../../wp-load.php'; 
require_once 'home-away-sync.php'; 

if (!$isDebug) header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');



$time_start = microtime(true);
    
global $wp_start;
global $wpdb;

if (!$isDebug) header('Cache-Control: max-age=300, public');

$data = array(
    'count' => 0,
    'current_timestamp' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
    'wp_time' => -1,
    'func_time' => -1,
    'data' => array()
);

$check_in = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat( 'U', strtotime('today') );
$stay_length = 7;
$twoWeekRental_stay_length = 14;

// get vars from query string
if(isset($_GET['check_in'])) {
    $check_in = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat( 'U', strtotime($_GET['check_in']) );
}
if(isset($_GET['stay_length'])) {
    $stay_length = filter_var($_GET['stay_length'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}

// set defaults
$today = new DateTime('today');
$currentYear = date("Y");

if ($isDebug) {
    echo "<p>check-in: " . $check_in->format('Y-m-d') . "</p>";
    echo "<p>stay length: " . $stay_length . "</p>";
    echo "<p>today: " . $today->format('Y-m-d') . "</p>";
}

if ( $check_in ) {

    $results = $wpdb->get_results( 
        $wpdb->prepare( 
            "
            SELECT a1.post_id, dtBeginDate, dtEndDate, dblRate, dblBookingFee, dblTransactionFee, dblSubtotal, dblMinStay, dblMaxStay, turnday.meta_value as turnDay
            FROM $wpdb->homeaway_Availability a1
                LEFT JOIN $wpdb->postmeta as turnday ON meta_key = 'turn_day' AND a1.post_id = turnday.post_id
            WHERE strChargeBasis = 'Nightly'
                AND dtBeginDate <= dtEndDate
                AND ( 
                    (
                        IF ( dblMinStay <= $stay_length , true, false )  
                        AND (
                            (IF(turnday.meta_value = 'friday', true, false) 
                                AND (
                                    (dtBeginDate <= %s AND %s <= dtEndDate)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtBeginDate AND dtBeginDate <= %s)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtEndDate AND dtEndDate <= %s)
                                )
                            )
                            OR (IF(turnday.meta_value = 'saturday', true, false) 
                                AND (
                                    (dtBeginDate <= %s AND %s <= dtEndDate)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtBeginDate AND dtBeginDate <= %s)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtEndDate AND dtEndDate <= %s)
                                )
                            )
                            OR (IF(turnday.meta_value = 'sunday', true, false) 
                                AND (
                                    (dtBeginDate <= %s AND %s <= dtEndDate)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtBeginDate AND dtBeginDate <= %s)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtEndDate AND dtEndDate <= %s)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                    OR
                    (
                        IF ( dblMinStay = $twoWeekRental_stay_length , true, false )  
                        AND (
                            (IF(turnday.meta_value = 'friday', true, false) 
                                AND (
                                    (dtBeginDate <= %s AND %s <= dtEndDate)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtBeginDate AND dtBeginDate <= %s)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtEndDate AND dtEndDate <= %s)
                                )
                            )
                            OR (IF(turnday.meta_value = 'saturday', true, false) 
                                AND (
                                    (dtBeginDate <= %s AND %s <= dtEndDate)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtBeginDate AND dtBeginDate <= %s)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtEndDate AND dtEndDate <= %s)
                                )
                            )
                            OR (IF(turnday.meta_value = 'sunday', true, false) 
                                AND (
                                    (dtBeginDate <= %s AND %s <= dtEndDate)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtBeginDate AND dtBeginDate <= %s)
                                    OR
                                    (%s <= dtEndDate AND dtEndDate <= %s)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            ORDER BY a1.post_id, dtBeginDate
            ",
            // JOIN
            $check_in->modify('-1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday Start
            $check_in->modify('+5 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday End
            $check_in->modify('-1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday Start
            $check_in->modify('+5 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday End
            $check_in->modify('-1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday Start
            $check_in->modify('+5 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday End
            $check_in->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'),                   // Saturday Start
            $check_in->modify('+6 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Saturday End
            $check_in->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'),                   // Saturday Start
            $check_in->modify('+6 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Saturday End
            $check_in->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'),                   // Saturday Start
            $check_in->modify('+6 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Saturday End
            $check_in->modify('+1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday Start
            $check_in->modify('+7 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday End
            $check_in->modify('+1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday Start
            $check_in->modify('+7 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday End
            $check_in->modify('+1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday Start
            $check_in->modify('+7 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday End

            $check_in->modify('-1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday Start
            $check_in->modify('+12 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday End
            $check_in->modify('-1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday Start
            $check_in->modify('+12 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday End
            $check_in->modify('-1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday Start
            $check_in->modify('+12 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Friday End
            $check_in->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'),                   // Saturday Start
            $check_in->modify('+13 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Saturday End
            $check_in->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'),                   // Saturday Start
            $check_in->modify('+13 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Saturday End
            $check_in->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'),                   // Saturday Start
            $check_in->modify('+13 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Saturday End
            $check_in->modify('+1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday Start
            $check_in->modify('+14 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday End
            $check_in->modify('+1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday Start
            $check_in->modify('+14 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday End
            $check_in->modify('+1 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday Start
            $check_in->modify('+14 day')->format('Y/m/d H:i:s'), // Sunday End
        ),
        ARRAY_A 
    );

    if ($isDebug) {
        echo "<p>Availibility Query</p><pre>" . print_r($wpdb->last_query, true) . "</pre>";
        echo "<p>Availibility Results</p><pre>" . print_r($results, true) . "</pre>";
    }

    
    $pricing = array();
    foreach ( $results as $row ) 
    {
        $id = $row["post_id"];

        if (!array_key_exists($id, $pricing)) {
            $pricing[$id] =  array(
                'id' => $id,
                'rate_total' => 0,
                'booking_fee' => 0,
                'transaction_percent' => 0,
                'day_cnt' => 0
            );
        }

        if ($row['dblBookingFee'] > 0 && $row['dblBookingFee'] > $pricing[$id]['booking_fee']) {
            $pricing[$id]['booking_fee'] = $row['dblBookingFee'];
        }
        if ($row['dblTransactionFee'] > 0 && $row['dblTransactionFee'] > $pricing[$id]['transaction_percent']) {
            $pricing[$id]['transaction_percent'] = $row['dblTransactionFee'];
        }
        $begin = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat( 'U', strtotime($row['dtBeginDate']) );
        $end = DateTimeImmutable::createFromFormat( 'U', strtotime($row['dtEndDate']) );

        if( $row['dblMinStay'] > $stay_length ){
            $stay_length = $row['dblMinStay'];
        } else{
            $stay_length = $stay_length;
        }
        
        for ($c = 0; $c < $stay_length ; $c++) {
            $dayModifier = 0;
            if ($row['turnDay'] == 'friday') {
                $dayModifier = -1;
            } else if ($row['turnDay'] == 'sunday') {
                $dayModifier = 1;
            }
            $currdate = $check_in->modify(''. ( $c + $dayModifier ) .' day');

            if ( $begin->getTimestamp() <= $currdate->getTimestamp() && $currdate->getTimestamp() <= $end->getTimestamp() ) {
                $pricing[$id]['rate_total'] += $row["dblRate"];
                $pricing[$id]['day_cnt'] += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($isDebug) echo "<p>Pricing Array</p><pre>" . print_r($pricing, true) . "</pre>";

    $pricing = array_values($pricing);

    $i = 0;
    foreach( $pricing as $item ) {
        if ($stay_length == $item['day_cnt']) {
            $sub_total = ceil( ($item['rate_total'] + $item['booking_fee']) * (1 + $item['transaction_percent']) );

            $data['data'][$i]['id'] = $item['id'];
            $data['data'][$i]['min_price'] = $sub_total;
            $data['data'][$i]['max_price'] = $sub_total;
            $i++;
        }
    }

}

$data['count'] = count($data['data']);

$time_end = microtime(true);

$data['wp_time'] = $time_start - $wp_start;
$data['func_time'] = $time_end - $time_start;

echo json_encode($data);
```